# Can I create and store a snapshot of a simpy simulation?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy, industrial

I am building a simulation of a production process using **simpy** and an agent (Heuristic or Reinforcement Learning via tensorforce) that allocates orders to stations in the production system.

Every simulation starts with an empty production system that is slowly getting filled with orders. In order to analyze my agents, I would like to see how they perform without that warm-up phase that initially fills the empty production system.

**Is there a way to create and save a "snapshot" of a simpy simulation** from which I can start at a later stage with different parameters (i.e., a different agent) again?

I have read through the simpy docs but could not find such a functionality. My current workaround is starting the simulation every time with an empty production system and changing the agent once the system is fully utilized. However I want to get away from this approach as it wastes a lot of computational time.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: perhaps pickling it could help. Whatever "it" is - hard to say without seeing any representative code.